# $\chi(\cdot)$ is an algebraic integer in $\mathbb{Q}$($\zeta_n$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory, cyclotomic-fields

Let $\chi(\cdot)$ be an irreducible (over $\mathbb{C}$) character of an representation in a finite Group G:

*Show that $\chi(g)$ is an algebraic integer in the cyclotomic
field $\mathbb{Q}$($\zeta_n$), where $\zeta_n$ := $e^{2\pi i/n}$.*

Any idea? Really idealess...

Comment: You need to specify $n$ Or say in some cyclotomic field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We know that $\chi(g)=tr(M(g))$, where $g \longmapsto M(g) \in GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ is a group homomorphism. 
So we know that $M(g)^{|G|}=I_n$, thus $M(g)$ is similar to some diagonal matrix where diagonal coefficients are powers of $\zeta_n$ (which is an algebraic integer in said cyclotomic field). Thus, so is their sum, which is the trace of the diagonal matrix similar to $M(g)$, which is $tr(M(g))=\chi(g)$.

Comment: The polynomial $X^{|G|}-1$ has $|G|$ distinct complex roots and vanishes at $M(g)$, so $M(g)$ is diagonalizable. Its eigenvalues must be roots of $X^{|G|}-1$, thus powers of $\zeta_n$.

Comment: $M(g)^{|G|}=M(g^{|G|})=M(e)=I$.